# How do I insert the image into article?

Tags: entities

[image]

I am using field image to insert image into article.
The image can't show in article body.

How do I insert the image into article?

Comment: what do you mean by `How do I insert the image into article?` you need to insert the image in the node page? or embed it in the `body` field of the content type?

Comment: @Drupalist can insert images into the body field

Comment: Then you need to use CK Editor module. it allows you to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of [Wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) and  [Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert) modules.

**Insert module :**

> Insert is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files
>   into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple
>   JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used
>   with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas
>   with a specific ImageCache preset.
>
> This module was previously known as FileField Insert.
>
> Features
>
> ```
> Support for all major WYSIWYG editors, including tinyMCE, CKeditor, the WYSIWYG project (the recommended approach), and plain
> ```
>
> text areas.
>       Insert images using ImageCache presets
>       Maximum width setting for inserted images (for combined use with the Image Resize Filter module)
>       Per-field insert configuration

also for caption images you can use [jcaption](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcaption) or [image caption](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_caption) modules

Comment: This looks awesome, can it add caption? @Zhilevan

Comment: @user73963 I update my answer, yes you can :D

Comment: How do I insert watermark with insert module? Can I define which taxanomy needs watermark?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wysiwyg option you can insert images into the body field.  There is a wysiwyg module that provides good integration and management and lets you use one of several engines.  If it is okay to have the image at the start or end of the body text, and not in the middle, then go to the Display Fields tab at the top of your screenshot and drag your image field into the appropriate order.  Also you can set image display size and other options from that area.

Comment: Yes, you can use the very popular [CK Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) for this.

Comment: If using wysiwyg module, I can't create a views block, the views can't select wysiwyg image. @DeveloperWeeks

Comment: In views, For example: If your field body has wysiwyg (from your node content type, not views), then you add the field body to your view, it should show the picture from wysiwyg (if I remember correctly)

Comment: @NoSssweat Field body is under which section in views?

Comment: under FIELDS you just have to add it, if you haven't already. When you click add, it should be listed as long as you created a Content view.